# Blinking cursor in TextView via Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, cursor

I want to create a blinking cursor in a TextView.. So far i got this:

```
    myTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTv);


    //blinking Cursors Thread
    class CursorThread extends Thread 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                myTv.setText("|");

                try 
                {
                    sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {}

                myTv.setText(" ");

                try 
                {
                    sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {}
            }  
        }
    }
    CursorThread cThread = new CursorThread();
    cThread.start();
```

If i ran this app i get a crash. What m i doing wrong ?
Im dont know many things about Threads...
Oh and this Thread is an inner class in my MainActivity of course.

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must access the UI thread from another thread with the `runOnUI` method like shown here

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        keresetTv.setText(" ");
    }
});
```

or by using a `handler.post(new Runnable...);`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative: subclass TextView and have its onDraw call `postInvalidateDelayed()` , effecting an invalidate of itself after a number of milliseconds.  Track time between calls in onDraw, and flash the cursor appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a view from another thread(that is not the main `UI` thread). You could use a `Handler` to modify your `TextView` from `CursorThread`.